# Unity C# User being charged the wrong amount

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

I'm a complete beginner to C# & Unity and have encountered an error within my shop code. If anyone could find the error and let me know it'd be greatly appreciated. Also any feedback on the code would be very useful as I've only recently started Unity.

I've currently got a shop layout, all in seperate panels, with 3 textboxes for the info, and then a purchase button. I want it so that when you click purchase it checks if you have enough money, if so it'll bring up a conformation that you want to purchase it, and then if you agree it will buy it.

Currently the issue is that whenever you buy something, it charges you 10, 20 and then 30, which is the prices of the 3 items. The way I've stored the price value is within the script which as been duplicated 3 times into each panel, all of which have the values in. Please help

`````
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Common;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using Unity.VisualScripting;

public class ShopLogic : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject shopUI;
    public string itemName;
    public string itemDescription;
    public int itemPrice;

    public bool ownsItem;

    GameObject objectParent;
    GameObject data;
    GameObject buttonTitle;
    GameObject buttonDescription;
    GameObject buttonPrice;

    GameObject confirmCanvas;
    GameObject confirmItemTitle;
    GameObject confirmDescription;
    GameObject confirmButton;

    public PlayerValues playerStats;

    public int currentPrice;

    void Start()
    {
        ownsItem = false;

        objectParent = transform.parent.gameObject;
        data = objectParent.transform.Find("Data").gameObject;

        buttonTitle = objectParent.transform.Find("Title").gameObject;
        buttonDescription = objectParent.transform.Find("Description").gameObject;
        buttonPrice = objectParent.transform.Find("Price").gameObject;

        shopUI = objectParent.transform.parent.gameObject;

        confirmCanvas = transform.parent.parent.Find("ConformationTab").gameObject;
        confirmButton = confirmCanvas.transform.Find("PurchaseButton").gameObject;

        confirmButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(ConfirmClick);


        string titleText = data.GetComponent<ShopLogic>().itemName;
        string descriptionText = data.GetComponent<ShopLogic>().itemDescription;
        int itemPrice = data.GetComponent<ShopLogic>().itemPrice;

        buttonTitle.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = titleText;
        buttonDescription.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = descriptionText;
        buttonPrice.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = itemPrice.ToString();
    }

    public void itemClick()
    {
        int itemPrice = data.GetComponent<ShopLogic>().itemPrice;
        string itemName = data.GetComponent<ShopLogic>().itemName;
        string itemDescription = data.GetComponent<ShopLogic>().itemDescription;
        int playerCoins = playerStats.Cash;

        if (playerCoins >= currentPrice)
        {
            Confirm(itemPrice, itemName, itemDescription);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Insufficient coins.");
        }
    }
    public void Confirm(int price, string itemName, string itemDescription)
    {
        currentPrice = price;
        confirmItemTitle = confirmCanvas.transform.Find("ItemTitle").gameObject;
        confirmDescription = confirmCanvas.transform.Find("ItemDescription").gameObject;

        confirmItemTitle.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = itemName;
        confirmDescription.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = itemDescription;
        confirmCanvas.transform.SetParent(transform.parent);
        confirmCanvas.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void ConfirmClick()
    {
        ownsItem = true;
        playerStats.Cash -= currentPrice;
        confirmCanvas.transform.SetParent(shopUI.transform);
        confirmCanvas.SetActive(false);

        Debug.Log("Player charged: " + currentPrice);
    }
}````
`````

Answer (score 1):

Basically this script is ShopLogic, so why do you keep on using GetComponent to get another ShopLogic and read values from there? Also you keep on reusing names "itemPrice", "itemName", "itemDescription" as a local variable while they are declared as fields, that might be tricky and cause malfunctions if you are careless.
Start with cleaning up like that and check if it works now

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Common;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using Unity.VisualScripting;

public class ShopLogic : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject shopUI;
    public string itemName;
    public string itemDescription;
    public int itemPrice;

    public bool ownsItem;

    GameObject objectParent;
    GameObject data;
    GameObject buttonTitle;
    GameObject buttonDescription;
    GameObject buttonPrice;

    GameObject confirmCanvas;
    GameObject confirmItemTitle;
    GameObject confirmDescription;
    GameObject confirmButton;

    public PlayerValues playerStats;

    public int currentPrice;

    void Start()
    {
        ownsItem = false;

        objectParent = transform.parent.gameObject;
        data = objectParent.transform.Find("Data").gameObject;

        buttonTitle = objectParent.transform.Find("Title").gameObject;
        buttonDescription = objectParent.transform.Find("Description").gameObject;
        buttonPrice = objectParent.transform.Find("Price").gameObject;

        shopUI = objectParent.transform.parent.gameObject;

        confirmCanvas = transform.parent.parent.Find("ConformationTab").gameObject;
        confirmButton = confirmCanvas.transform.Find("PurchaseButton").gameObject;

        confirmButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(ConfirmClick);

        buttonTitle.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = itemName;
        buttonDescription.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = itemDescription;
        buttonPrice.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = itemPrice.ToString();
    }

    public void itemClick()
    {
        int playerCoins = playerStats.Cash;

        if (playerCoins >= currentPrice)
        {
            Confirm(itemPrice, itemName, itemDescription);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Insufficient coins.");
        }
    }
    public void Confirm(int price, string confirmedItemName, string confirmendItemDescription)
    {
        currentPrice = price;
        confirmItemTitle = confirmCanvas.transform.Find("ItemTitle").gameObject;
        confirmDescription = confirmCanvas.transform.Find("ItemDescription").gameObject;

        confirmItemTitle.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = confirmedItemName;
        confirmDescription.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = confirmendItemDescription;
        confirmCanvas.transform.SetParent(transform.parent);
        confirmCanvas.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void ConfirmClick()
    {
        ownsItem = true;
        playerStats.Cash -= currentPrice;
        confirmCanvas.transform.SetParent(shopUI.transform);
        confirmCanvas.SetActive(false);

        Debug.Log("Player charged: " + currentPrice);
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason I keep using GetComponent to go into the same script is because there are 3 panels containing each seperate item being sold, which has the ShopLogic script in each. The shop logic script creates the values itemName, itemDescription and itemPrice so that I can change it in the inspector, which means all values are different. I have very little experience with unity so I do not know of a better way to do this at the moment. I use getcomponent whilst the game is running because I don't know which script it is running, meaning I do not know the values. @Paweł Łęgowski

Comment: So one script ShopLogic controls 3 others scripts ShopLogic? I don't get it. Maybe you should create one script "ShopLogic" and other script "ShopPanelLogic" if this approach is not working

Comment: Okay, I'm going to attempt to make a new one in a new scene, thank you for your help :)